# Adding touch to Grub2?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, touchscreen

Are there any projects out there working to add touch sensitivity to Grub2?

If not what touch libraries exist in Ubuntu 13.04 that may be a possible candidates to implement this after integrating?

---

**Edit:** March 14, 2013 @ 5:10PM PST

I have been searching hard and have found the following packages under Ubuntu 13.04:

- [muTouch](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/xserver-xorg-input-mutouch/1:1.3.0-1build3)  ( I believe this came from uTouch, an older package that Ubuntu used to use. )
- [libfile-touch-perl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/libfile-touch-perl/0.08-1)
- [tslib](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/tslib/1.0-11)
- [pymt](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/pymt/0.5.1-0ubuntu3)
- [touchegg](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/touchegg/1.1.1-0ubuntu1)
- [libframe6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/frame/2.5.0daily13.03.12-0ubuntu1)

I will be going through these and hopefully come up with a answer soon.  If you are familiar with any of these libraries a reply would be beautiful.  In my brief passing of each of these it seemed that **tslib** and **pymt** as they are not platform dependant like grub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to ask [Stephen Webb](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StephenMWebb) who currently leads the Unity Technical Team about touch input. I contacted him because he used to be the lead developer on the [uTouch-geis](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/utouch-geis) package which was split into three different packages [Frame](https://launchpad.net/frame), [Geis](https://launchpad.net/geis), and [Grail](https://launchpad.net/grail).  These are the primary touch screen controls for 13.04 and he is also heavily involved in other [multi-touch projects](https://launchpad.net/canonical-multitouch). I asked him about learning more about touch device input and my idea.  Here is what he had to say:

---

**I want to have Grub2 register a single tap event, no more (multi touch not needed-I think).  Purpose would be to select from the boot menu.**

> You're going to have a challenge getting touch to work from boot
>   loader code.
>
> Many (but not all) touch input devices have device drivers that work
>   to the Microsoft HID protocol.  You'd need to replicate that driver
>   technology into GRUB2, and then figure out how to map that into
>   something GRUB2 would understand as input.  Sounds like work.

**Is there any resources you can lead me to that would help me understand how touch devices work?**

> That's complicated.  There's a lot of different technologies,
>   connected to the host in different ways, talking different protocols,
>   delivering different data.
>
> There's some good documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/hh852381).

**Are there any single tap libraries you can suggest or multi touch one? Do you have any other suggestions on how to move forward?**

> Well, in the Linux stack there's the firmware in the touch processor,
>   which feeds data to the device driver in the kernel, which translates
>   into the evdev protocol, which is read by the x.org driver and
>   converted into the XI2 protocol, or if there's nothing looking for XI2
>   touch events, then converts *that* into an XI mouse event, and an X11
>   event gets sent to the client.  All you have at the boot loader level
>   is direct input from the touch processor.